# how to transfer subscribers from list 1 to list 2 using Aweber API

Tags: php, aweber

I have checked with Aweber customers service and they told me their internal function wouldn't allow me to transfer subscribers from list 1 to list 2. But he says that an API would help.

I'm able to communicate with Aweber's API and can add subscribers to the lists and even can get all my aweber account lists.

So I just want to confirm that the Aweber API can allow me to transfer subscribers from list 1 to list 2?

Say I have List A and List B in my account, now I want to combine both list in to List C, I can transfer all my subscribers into List C without having them to sign up and confirm again? Can this be done with Aweber API? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. https://labs.aweber.com/docs/reference/1.0#subscriber

The subscriber entity has a custom POST method available called "move".

Comment: There aweber API documentation seems lacking a lot things. The have not given any code example of doing this using API.

Comment: If you are using PHP then I would suggest using their PHP SDK instead of connecting straight to the API. And yes I agree more samples would certainly be beneficial